# nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16

Tags: nginx, centos, plesk

I'm new to NGINX and I'm trying to setup minimal working thing. So I trying to run https with nginx and supervisor (by this example). But I can't configure Nginx right and getting the following error:

```
Error Code: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed . 



 GNU nano 2.0.9          File: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                           

#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
location ~^/wp-json/ {
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}
http {
    include   mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;

 #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

It looks correct. server directive is in http as it should be. And http is parent directive. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The docs about [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) clearly mention that location can only be defined in the `server` context. @Chris's answer is right. Also, for wordpress, there's tons of nginx examples out there for any vhosts.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean by "server directive is in http" - I'll assume you're referring to what's in the files included from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`.

Anyway, if you're trying to enhance the `server` directive in one of the included files, you'll have to do that there. If you'd like to define a new server, you'll need a block within `http`. And within that block, you'll add your `location` block.

```
http {
  #...
  server {
    #...
    location ~^/wp-json/ {
      #...
      rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
      #...
    }
    #...
  }
  #...
}
```

If you're just getting started, maybe this is a good resource: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html?